Unable to run docker container throw error bash: line 1: ./setup.sh: cannot execute: required file not found
I am trying to run my app inside Docker container it is working fine in macOS and linux system. But when I am trying to run docker compose up in Windows system then 2 containers working fine but Node app container stopped.
This is docker-compose.yml file here you can see setup.sh this is available in the current folder also.
version: '3.1'

services:
  app:
    container_name: vitabletech-node-app
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "chmod +x ./setup.sh && ./setup.sh"
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:${PORT}" # Use the port number defined in .env for the host
    env_file:
      - .env

  db:
    container_name: vitabletech-db
    image: mariadb:10.6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: vitabletech-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${PHPMYADMIN_PORT}:80
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

I checked the container log why it's stopped then in log I got this error message bash: line 1: ./setup.sh: cannot execute: required file not found.
I also tried to remove this command: bash -c "chmod +x ./setup.sh && ./setup.sh" like command: bash -c "tail -f /dev/null".
Now the container started and inside container I checked that file is available but still showing not found.
# ls
LICENSE    app                    config    database            node_modules       package.json         setup.sh
README.md  commitlint.config.cjs  coverage  docker-compose.yml  package-lock.json  postman-collections
# ./setup.sh
sh: 2: ./setup.sh: not found

So after two days spend to finding what was the issue I found that file type is CRLF in Windows system as I changed to LF then it started working. Anyone have any idea how I can make the project cross platform?
Actually I used Docker so that no issue to configure anything but still getting issues. One more thing I notice that server is running by nodemon if I change anything in server.js or any file that is also not reflecting but if I am changing that file CLRF to LF then working.
# ./setup.sh  

> node-express-api-bootstrap@2.0.0 prepare
> husky


added 1 package, and audited 1155 packages in 7s

194 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.6.0      
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.6.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.6.0 to update!
npm notice 

> node-express-api-bootstrap@2.0.0 dev
> nodemon app/server.js

[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`  
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app/server.js`       
Server is running on port 5000.


Your app container doesn't seem to be building a reusable image; instead, it's using an isolated node image to run code that lives exclusively on the host.  Can you use Node on the host system, connecting to this containerized database?  This could help if a host Bourne-compatible shell honors the host's line-ending conventions.

@DavidMaze you mean to say install node in local and for database use docker container right ?
